# Select first part of string

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, awk

How do I pull a substring from a string. For example, from the string:

```
'/home/auto/gift/surprise'
```

take only:

```
'/home/auto/'
```

Note that `'/home/auto/gift/surprise'` may vary, i.e., instead of having 4 directory levels, it may go to 6 or 8, yet I'm only interested in the first 2 folders.

Here's what I've tried so far, without success:

```
$ pwd
'/home/auto/gift/surprise' 
$ pwd | sed 's,^\(.*/\)\?\([^/]*\),\1,'
'/home/auto/gift/'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is better to use `cut` for this:

```
$ echo "/home/auto/gift/surpris" | cut -d/ -f1-3
/home/auto
$ echo "/home/auto/gift/surpris/bla/bla" | cut -d/ -f1-3
/home/auto
```

Note that `cut -d/ -f1-3` means: strip the string based on the delimiter `/`, then print from the 1st to the 3rd parts.

Or also `awk`:

```
$ echo "/home/auto/gift/surpris" | awk -F/ 'OFS="/" {print $1,$2,$3}'
/home/auto
$ echo "/home/auto/gift/surpris/bla/bla" | awk -F/ 'OFS="/" {print $1,$2,$3}'
/home/auto
```

Comment: Absolutely agree, no need to use something overpowered like sed for a simple task that can be done with cut.

Comment: Maybe 2 characters less, `cut -d/ -f1-3`

Comment: Oh thanks @devnull, you always improve our answers :) Even one char less: `cut -d/ -f-3` but it's a bit tricky, prefer yours.

Comment: @fedorqui: that was nice (`-f-3`)

Answer (score 3):

You may use parameter substitution, which is POSIX defined:

```
$ s="/home/auto/gift/surprise"
$ echo ${s%/*/*}
/home/auto
```